# SSRS report display varies completely in PDF when compared to on screen display

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have couple of SSRS reports deployed to test server.

The report layout/formatting looks OKAY on the screen but when I export to PDF and view in PDF, everything is messed up.

For example, I see two columns shown in separate page. Even one of the tablix region comes up separately in another page.

So totally one page on-screen display comes to PDF in about 3 to 4 pages.

Also the 2nd and 3rd pages are always blank.

Did I mess up the report defination or any width/height parameters? The report is set to print in landscape and is in inches.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to increase the page width, from the Report menu. This will keep all your columns on a single page. As for blank pages when report is exported to PDF, you will have to squeeze out all white space while designing the report. The size of the canvas should not be more than what is just needed. If you have groups on your report and there are page breaks separating each group, setting the `ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace` property of the Report to true will ensure there are no blank pages at the end.